# Move the sites' information panel in the Stack Exchange's "All Sites" page inside the screen (remove overflow with scroll)

Tags: feature-request, design, stack-exchange, user-interface

I would like to suggest that when opening a site's information panel in the Stack Exchange's ["All Sites" page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) that it doesn't overflow outside the visible window. This is how it currently is:

[image: List of sites]

[image: Site information]

[image: After scrolling]

I think something like this would work better:

[image: Solution]